# Initializing a property in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have a constructor I am trying to build with the header `public KsuPoint(double x0, double y0)`

now i also have properties in the class as shown below

```
private double x;

    public double X
    {
        get { return x; }

    }

    private double y;

    public double Y
    {
        get { return y; }

    }
```

This constructor is suppose to initialize the properties X and Y ...

is this correct? or am i off?

```
public KsuPoint(double x0, double y0)
    {
        new KsuPoint(x0, y0);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The constructor needs to map it's parameters to the private fields of the class - here is what your class should look like:

```
class KsuPoint
{
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public double X { get { return x; } }
    public double Y { get { return y; } }

    public KsuPoint(double x0, double y0)
    {
        this.x = x0;
        this.y = y0;
    }
}
```

If you want to be more concise you could do this:

```
class KsuPoint
{
    public double X { get; private set; }
    public double Y { get; private set; }

    public KsuPoint(double x0, double y0)
    {
        this.X = x0;
        this.Y = y0;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok.. so everyone pretty much agree it should something to this effect?
this.x = x0;
        this.y = y0;

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No you only use new when you want to create a new object of the class typically outside the class.

```
public KsuPoint(double x0, double y0)
{
    x = x0;
    y = y0;
}
```

Somewhere else in your code you would have:

```
KsuPoint point = new KsuPoint(3, 4);
```

If you are using C# 3.0 you can also do this:

```
class KsuPoint
{
    public double X { get; private set; }
    public double Y { get; private set; }

    public KsuPoint(double x0, double y0)
    {
        X = x0;
        Y = y0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The capitalised X and Y are getters only. This would be problematic.

Comment: yea my instructions said to make it read only. and take out setters :/

Answer (score 0):

No, that would result in a bad case of infinite recursion. Just assign the values normally, i.e.

```
x = x0;
y = y0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add setters, like this:

```
public double X
{
    get { return x; }
    set { x = value; }
}
```

If you just want simple getters and setters, this syntax is shorter, and easier to read in my opinion:

```
public double x0 { get; set; }
public double y0 { get; set; }
```

Then you simply assign the parameter to the field, like many of the other answers show.